# Dynamic Ip Changer

Tags: networking, dynamic, ip

I am a newbie VB.NET 2005 programmer. I would like to develop an application that does not show my real IP Address instead it shows some fake IP Address. There is a commercial Application called "HIDE MY IP" it uses the same functionality.

I don't want to make same software, but i need this aspect of the software for my new application.

Any Help regarding this? Where to get Started?

Is this possible in VB.NET 2005?

Comment: You are going to need to provide more details on who you are hiding your 'ip' from.

Either way, its pretty much a lost cause. You can't spoof your IP and have two way traffic, and even if your application simply reports a false IP to the user, it is trivial to find the real IP using other tools.

Comment: In what context do you want to "hide" your IP? From the user of your software? From websites you visit? From big brother?

Comment: I want to hide my IP from the website i visit. Like i want that website to see some fake ip of mine visiting their website.

There will be a form and a web browser control on it.
This website will be visited in that web browser control in VB.NET 2005.

Answer (score 3):

Truly hiding your IP would require that you are leveraging some type of proxy service or tunneling service (VPN) which is relaying your requests on your behalf and acting as an intermediary.  While your internal IP is probably private and thus truly not visible to the outside world anyway, the IP address you use through your service provider which is public cannot be obsfucated or hidden.  Only if you relay can you hide your true address, but your relay will be public.  Without a real address you cannot do any IP communications and thus all protocols will be unidirectional and fail.

You could write a VB.NET 20005 application which simply connects you to a proxy server or tunnels your Internet traffic through a VPN which in turn hides your IP address.

Comment: You should note that even going through a proxy, there is a potential to trace the ip communication back to you (by using logs from the proxy). There are all sorts of ideas of making this anonymous (like the torproject.org, but even there, I think there are still privacy concerns.

Comment: Basically i was reading some Networking Book in .NET and i found that you can view the ip- packet that is send by your computer. 

Now, If we can view this packet then can't we change the Source IP Address in the header of the Ip Packet??? I just want this Packet to contain a fake IP Address and not my own. 

My Application needs me to change the fake IP every 20 minutes or so... and a IP can be used once in 5 hrs. So, i guess i can't tunnel my packets through a proxy server..( as they are too less )

Thank you for replies :)

Comment: Pradeep, if you change the source IP address there is no way for you to receive a response from the destination thus transactional protocols like TCP, HTTP, etc. will fail.

Comment: Thanx :D i will rethink the concepts. Actually i just dont want the website i am visiting to know my ip address.